# Understanding a step while calculating the gradient of the log-likelihood of Restricted Boltzmann Machines

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, machine-learning

I'm reading [this paper](http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/AItRBM-proof.pdf) about Restricted Boltzmann Machines. However there are two steps that I don't understand when they compute the gradient of the log-likelihood (section 4.1). Here is a screenshot for the formulas that are troubling me:

[image]

What I don't understand in particular:

1- How the multiplication became a summation in (problem 1)?

2- Why the summation is equal to 1 in (problem 2)?!